# Tablesorter stickyHeaders widget not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, tablesorter

I'm having trouble making my table header to stick using the tablesorter widget.  I have the following for my table page:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/theme.default.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.tablesorter.js' %}"></script>
<div id="tableWrap" style="position:relative;">
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <caption> ... </caption>
    <thead>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').tablesorter({
            sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
            widgetOptions: {
                stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#tableWrap' 
            },
    });
});

</script>
```

I tried labeling my table tag and also creating a div tag around my table, but nothing seems to work.
The jQuery version is v1.11.2, and the tablesorter version is v2.31.1.

Comment: The sticky headers widget also needs to be loaded after tablesorter. It is included in the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` file, or separate from other widgets in the `widget-stickyHeader.js` file.

Comment: Thank you Mottie, my header is behaving correctly now:)

Comment: So I got the header to stick, but now it doesn't align with the table body anymore after scrolling. I checked the documentation and played with the various offset widgetOptions, but the header still doesn't align...

Comment: Make sure the element wrapping the table (a `<div>` or whatever) has a `position: relative` set on it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, I tried putting the position modifier in the table, thead, & tbody tags, but there was no effect...

Comment: The position needs to be set on the parent element wrapping the table.

Comment: Still doesn't work, tried putting the div with the position modifier around the table or around thead didn't do the trick...I  edited the original post to reflect the addition of parent div.

Comment: Adding widgetOptions: {stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#tableWrap'} doesn't work either:(

Comment: I'm thinking of using stickyHeaders_offset under widgetOptions, but it only allows header to be shifted up & down.  Is there a modifier allowing left & right shift? Currently I have a left sidebar, whose space is occupied by the sticky header when the original header is scrolled away.

Comment: Leave the `stickyHeaders_attachTo` option as `null` - https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/f36416oy/109/ - If you still can't get it to work, please modify this demo to show the problem.

Comment: Thank you Mottie, I created another post showing the problem since this one is getting off topic